# How to make a sortable table on html?

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

So this is my simple php code just to output them on a simple table. I was hoping I make it a sortable table and i do not understand most of the sources from online. Could someone show me a simple or at least the way to do it? I could also go for a drop down menu to select how to list the following data columns!

```
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$connect){
    die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("safedrive", $connect);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";

$myData = mysql_query($sql,$connect);

echo "<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Model</th>
<th>Year</th>
<th>Plate Number</th>
<th>City</th>
<th>Country</th>
</tr>";

while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $record['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['email'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['firstName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['lastName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['model'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['Year'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['plateNumber'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['city'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['country'] . "</td>";
echo "<br />";
}

echo "</table>";
```

I understand it is probably better done in the HTML tag, but I would like to hear some proper opinions.

Comment: Why not do it with SQL instead? Using [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) or [`ORDER BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html)

Comment: Actually, it is better done in the MYSQL query.  MYSQL is optimized for this kind of task, HTML is not.

Comment: Yeah i thought of it as well which actually made it simpler, but i thought why not just give the user some functionality. Anyway thanks for all the input guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this : [TableSorter 2.0](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) , you just need to install the plugin and configure a bit the js file. All is well explained on the site

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I will have a look through this!

Comment: np , if you succeed don't forget to mark it as answered